# Pixels, Density, Screen Resolution - of a Bitmap on Surface View?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

Im wondering if any one can help me get my Logic right about these principles with respect to my program.
I have a surface view on whose canvas i am drawing out a bitmap.
I found this piece of coding that would work out the bitmaps size on different resolutions and screen density.

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
   Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        Log.e("XXX", "Display w/h: " +size.x + "/" + size.y);

    bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.speedo); 
    int width = bmp1.getWidth();
    int height = bmp1.getHeight();
    Log.e("XXX", "w/h: " + width + "/" + height);

    float scaleWidth = metrics.scaledDensity;
    float scaleHeight = metrics.scaledDensity;
    Log.e("XXX", "w/h: " + scaleWidth + "/" + scaleHeight);

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    bmp2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

I have logged my values on 3 devices, after drawing it out on the Canvas.

1. GenyMotion Emulator (598x360) [scale1.0]
2. Lg Optimus2x (800x480) [scale1.5]
3. OnePlus1(1980x1080) [scale3.0]

The image(bitmap) i have made(in Adobe) is 800 by 179 pixels @ 72 pixels/inch

in GENYMOTION= it appears at 267 x 60

in Lg = it appears at 400 x 90

in OnePlus1= it appears at 800 x 179

I get how the dimensions vary according to the scale, BUT in the 1plus1 though it said 800 in length, it was longer than the screen ie 1980!? How can that be?
could someone explain me the logic to what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I found out the reason:- Its because of an RnD error on my part.

After the bmp2 is created and then drawn, i hadnt measured it. so it actually was 800x3=2400 which is > 1980(screen length)!